# How can I give write-access of a folder to all users in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I installed apache2 on Ubuntu just now, and noticed that the /var/www folder is protected. I can just `sudo` everything but I would rather just give it write access.

How can I do this?

I tried `sudo chmod 7777 /var/www` but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a publicly accessible server, or does it have no direct connection to the internet?

If the former it is important that you consider security decisions - servers on the internet are constantly under attack (have a look in your /var/log/messages or equivalent).

Comment: this is just my laptop, it is not accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

To best share with multiple users who should be able to write in `/var/www`, it should be assigned a common group. For example the default group for web content on Ubuntu and Debian is `www-data`. Make sure all the users who need write access to `/var/www` are in this group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data <some_user>
```

Then set the correct permissions on /var/www.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

Additionally, you should make the directory and all directories below it "set GID", so that all *new* files and directories created under `/var/www` are owned by the `www-data` group.

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
```

Find all files in `/var/www` and add read and write permission for owner and group:

```
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```

You might have to log out and log back in to be able to make changes if you're editing permission for your own account.

Comment: that's pretty tedious... I can't just give users access to it, as if it were any other folder?

Comment: That *is* how you give access to it. It's quicker to copy and paste the commands than try to navigate through a GUI file manager's dialogs to do the same thing. Long term it helps you if you read the manual pages for chmod and chgrp, at least ("man chmod").

Comment: perhaps I didn't understand the commands the first time I read it, and your edit makes it much more clear.

Comment: +1 for guid to force apache permissions. works well with umask of 027. If something needs writes access, it's as easy as chmod g+w dir/

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say this is awesome advice that is very concise and simple to follow while explaining everything you need to know. Well said. Upvoted and starred for future use. :)

Comment: @jtimberman The last 2 cmds looks like it should only run once. How to make it idempotent in chef? Actually I'm using these steps in chef!

Comment: Helped me out more than anything else I could find. Thanks.

Comment: you may want to add that for changes to take effect you need to reload user group assignments, maybe a clean system restart would be better if that's convenient for you

Comment: Why is your group permission command `sudo chmod -R g+w` and not `g+rw` or `g+rwX`?

Comment: +1 for logout and login again; it worked just after I did that. Thanks

Comment: How to make a brand new file have `w` permission for group?

Answer (score 84):

Read+Write:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /var/www
```

Read+Write+Execute:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www
```

Comment: what does the 'a' mean? all?

Comment: a is for all users
https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions

Answer (score 43):

There's a simpler way to do this, try doing this command.

```
sudo chmod -R 757 /var/www
```

Essentially, the `chmod` command alters permissions and the `-R` switch applies to files and directories recursively. Then it is simply giving the correct permissions to use.

Comment: Could you give some insight on what the command does for the OP?

Comment: -1 for lack of explanation. Besides, `chmod $permissions -R $file` isn't valid…

Comment: it is options then permissions not the other way around

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 757 /var/www`

Comment: please someone experienced suggest an edit with brief explanation about this.

Comment: Be careful: This really grants access to *everybody* on the system, which can be dangerous.  (I know this is what was asked, but most of the time it is not what you really want.)

Comment: `-R` is recursive, it's not "affects all users"

Comment: Having a 7 as the last digit certainly does affect all users.  I don't think it's worth "fixing" the answer, it's an answer that technically works but is a bad idea, for the same reason as all the other answers that involve giving all users write access are a bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

You can also replicate what jtimberman suggested using [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).  The [setfacl](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setfacl.htm) command accepts -s to replace an existing ACL or -m to modify it; -R to make directory ACLs recursive; and -d to make the specified settings the default, which is useful if you're anticipating forthcoming user accounts.

These just set the permissions as you would for the user, group, other, and mask using chmod:

```
setfacl -m u::rwx, g::r-x, o::---, m:rwx DIRECTORY
```

And this could be how you'd do it for a specified user or his/her group:

```
setfacl -m u:USERNAME:rwx, g:USERNAME:r-x DIRECTORY
```

And of course, the strength is that you can designate any specific user, multiple users, etc., all without having to modify your group settings.  And unlike chmod, if you want some groupies to have access to one directory and other groupies to have access only to another, it's actually possible with setfacl.  Finally, to view a directory's ACLs, run [getfacl](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_getfacl.htm):

```
getfacl DIRECTORY
```

And you can specify -R to see the ACLs for subdirectories or -d to see the defaults.

Answer (score 5):

**The quick & easy answer** -

a. Add (*-a*) your user (*user_name*) to the group (*-G*) *www-data*.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data user_name
```

b. Give the Group (*g*) the same (*=*) permissions as the owning User (*u*) of */var/www* Recursively (*-R*).

```
sudo chmod -R g=u /var/www
```

Explanation: Apache 2 on Debian/Ubuntu sets the User & Group *www-data* as the Owner of */var/www*. The default permissions for the User are "View & Modify Content", however the Group can only "View Content". So adding yourself to the www-data Group and giving it the same permissions as the wwww-data User, is a quick and easy way to get developing. I do this for all my localhost (PC/Laptop) Web Development environments.

Comment: This is bad for security. The reason www-user was created was for it to be a user with no (or minimal, in the case of files the web server MUST write to) write permissions so that anyone who compromises the web server can't do much damage and can't install custom code. If you give www-user write access to your website that's breaking that open. Use one of the solutions that involves creating a new user group.

Comment: To clarify, making the files world-writable is similarly a bad idea, hence the recommendation to use a group, just NOT the web server's restricted permissions group

Answer (score 3):

I typicall use

```
chmod g+w /folder/ -R
```

It's almost self-explaining.

It adds everyone in the `g`roup of `/folder/` to have `w`rite access (`+w`) , `-R` is for recursion for sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

0

Open Terminal and Type

`chmod ugo+rwx /home/eallen/Downloads`

or

`chmod 777 /home/eallen/Downloads`

"/home/eallen/Downloads" Replace it with your directory/foldername

if you want to remove all permission then type

`chmod -rwx /home/eallen/Downloads`

Comment: Your answer will be more useful if you were to explain why this would work.

Comment: RWX = READ WRITE EXECUTION PERMISSION
UGO = USER GROUP OTHER PERMISSION

Answer (score -3):

Can you just try `chmod 0777 /var/www` ?

A word of warning: if you let everybody access this folder, that means the hackers can access this folder if they gain access to your system.  That's why it's better to create a group of permissible users, and give that group write access.

Comment: so why offer this as a solution, and then immediately discredit it? -1 vote

Answer (score -3):

First you enter the particular folder path, then using this command …

```
chmod -R 777 foldername
chown username:username foldername
```

Comment: Wow, that's bad! You don't give a 777 with a -R -- especially if the person asking the question is a newbie and doesn't understand the risks.

Comment: True enough @recluze.