# linux - installed wordpress lack write problems

Tags: linux, ftp, apache-http-server, wordpress

I have recently installed wordpress but I have run into the problem that when i try to install plugins and themes i lack the permissions to write files.

My OS is linux ofc, running thru ssh terminal.

I have tried the following things to give permissions to the user.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

I have also tried doing as described in [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux),
when i tried

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data <some_user>
```

I got the message

```
could not resolve host <host-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you should be using the 'www-data' user or something else is very dependent upon your distribution. 'www-data' is very Debian-centric and also often used by their downstream derivative distributions.

Try running 'ps axufww | grep "[a]pache" '. The appropriate USER is the first column.

If you're using something derived from RedHat, it's probably 'apache' instead.

I'm not familiar with a distribution named "OFC", but I'd recommend looking at /etc/passwd to see if any listing in there have '/var/www'. If there is one, that's the user that you should be using. The appropriate group in /etc/group is frequently the same name as the user in /etc/passwd.