# Setting permissions on /var/www is not working correctly for subdirectories and files

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I followed these [instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux) (in the accepted answer) for setting up permissions on my /var/www/ folder.

I'm using the www-data group as it says to use. jdownes and testuer1 are both memebers of the group.

When jdownes (or any other www-data member) creates a file in /var/www they are able to edit it just fine. If another user (testuser1) in the www-data group goes to edit and save it, they are able to save but get the following error.

[image]

Here are the permissions for /var/www and the permissions on the file...

[image]

I have root access to the server and have been setting all permissions using putty not winscp.
Is the issue that the owner is not www-data for new files? If so, how can I force all new files to use www-data as the owner?

Comment: The images seem to be from a Windows PC? Is that correct? If so, your tags and the question are misleading.

Comment: How are my images and tags misleading? I'm using Putty/WINSCP to access a Ubuntu web server (as such have tagged it as linux). Also, the folder /var/www is a linux directory that you typically wouldn't see in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do, assume `www-data` is the user and group apache is running at and that for `/var/www` the owner is you and the group is  `www-data`:

```
chmod 755 /var/www
chmod g+s /var/www
```

The `chmod g+s` (set groupid) will ensure that new files will have the same group as the `/var/www` folder (`www-data`). `chmod 755 /var/www` ensures apache (through the www-data group) can read the folder and the user has read-write access. You need to have sufficient rights to do this.

In WinSCP set the group at least RX and user RWX and set the GID for the folder `/var/www`.

The reason apache fails is the missing X bit on the user and group for that folder (is 0664, should be 0755), it cannot read (= execute) the folder.

For files, 644 is sufficient: you are not required to set the GID.

Comment: Now testuser1 is unable to create files under /var/www... as you can see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1EoOa.png)

Comment: Should it be the following? "chmod 775 /var/www"